# In C, how can a store long strings (example passwords)

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare, c-strings

Well, I've got this programm checking passwords. It works fine if I set the second array (that is the for loop) to 8 digits. But as soon as the pw needs to be longer than 8 digits the whole thing goes wrong (since the for loop goes for 10 digits).

I thought declaring the first array to be MAXLINE long would work, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

```
/* IMPORT ---------------------- */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* CONST------------------ */
#define MAXDIGIT 10000
/* VARIABLES (global) ---------- */

/* MAIN--------------- */
int main()
 {
  /* VARIABLES (local) --------- */
    /* VARIABLES (local) --------- */


  // ENTERED PW: 
  char EnterCode[MAXDIGIT];  
  int i;


  // REAL PW: 
  char arr[MAXDIGIT] = "123456789";  //"YKJ98LGDDF";
  int j;

  printf("PW: "); // for testing

  for (j = 0 ; j < 8; ++j){
     printf("%c", arr[j]);
  }

  /* Intro --------------------- */
  printf("\nPlease enter code of authorization: ");

  for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

      scanf("%c", &EnterCode[i]);
      printf("%c", EnterCode[i]); // test 1
  }




      if (strcmp(EnterCode,arr) == 0){
          printf("\nAccess authorized.\n");
      }else{
         printf("\nAccess denied!\n");
      }

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You never insert `'\0'` character into the `EnterCode`. `strcmp` requires that strings are correctly terminated.

Comment: Read the input until you encounter a new line character...

Comment: `EnterCode` is most likely **not** null-terminated

Comment: also, don't put 10000 chars on the stack, use the heap (i.e. malloc)

Answer (score 1):

***Although you*** *can* ***put scanf in a loop***, you do not need to do that in your application:

If the passcode is going to be captured in a string, simply declare a *reasonable* length string, use it to read user's input in a single call:

```
char EnterCode[20];//20 is just for illustration, pick any reasonable length for your application

printf("enter your passcode:\n");
scanf("%19s", EnterCode);  //limit characters read to 19 (leaving room for terminating NULL)
```

***For an exceptionally long pass-code***,
rather than creating memory on the stack:

```
#define MAXDIGIT 10000
char EnterCode[MAXDIGIT];//uses a large block of memory from a limited source
```

Place it on the heap:

```
char *EnterCode = {0};  
EnterCode = malloc(MAXDIGIT); //also uses a large block of memory, but from a much much larger source
```

When you are done using EnterCode, free the memory:

```
free(EnterCode);
```

Comment: I would use `"%19s"` for `scanf` format control string.

Comment: Note: Using `"%19s"` prevent using space, tab, etc. as part of the password.  Further, should the user enter a "123 456", the "123" will be the password and "456' will remain in `stdin`.  Using `"%19[^\n]%*c"` or `fgets()` may be a better approach.

Comment: @chux - First thanks!  That is a useful suggestion.  However, I do not see a single response (beyond the question) from OP on this entire page, and it is a little less interesting answering (or improving an answer to) someones question when the feeling is there is little or no real interest in the answer by the the asker.  Would you agree? :)

Comment: @ryyker  True about OP - yet others contributors, like yourself, typically provide some nifty insights.

Answer (score 0):

In C language strings end with '\0'.

Therefore, your password should be "123456789" and after entering the "EnterCode" 
set EnterCode[10] = '\0' (in your code).

Comment: `"123456789"` means gimme a null-terminated string. `"123456789\0"` means gimme a string with 2 null-terminations, for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    scanf("%c", &EnterCode[i]);
    printf("%c", EnterCode[i]); // test 1
}
```

with

```
scanf("%s", EnterCode);
```

and try again.